# How to get stock data and add it to a django model?

Tags: python, django, yahoo-finance

Hay,
I am building a finance website where there is a stock model. I want the price to update automatically in a intfield when the website is running.

Answer (score 0):

Read data using pandas data reader:

```
import pandas
import pandas_datareader as pdr
ticker = 'DAX'
start = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30*9) # amount of days from required date
pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker,start).to_csv('dax.csv')
dax = pandas.read_csv('dax.csv')
pandas.to_csv('sample.csv') #downloading the data
```

Comment: How do I download it?